# Oppenheim and Willsky Signals and Systems Solutions

Tags: discrete-signals

Hi All: This list has been great for me as a beginner but I decided to work my way through Oppenheim and Willsky and Mahab  "Signals and Systems" book since I still get sometimes confused by even basic questions asked on this list.

I also do some of the problems but sometimes I get stuck. So I've looked and found solutions manuals on the internet. The solutions are okay but sometimes pretty succinct. So, does anyone know if the manual written by Oppenheim himself (it can be purchased on Amazon but it's not cheap ) is better than the ones on the internet ? Amazon doesn't have a "look inside" feature for that book so I can't tell. Thanks.

I forgot to include that I am using the second edition.

Comment: Hardly any textbook author writes the solutions manual as a sole effort. Mostly, the solutions are written by teaching assistants while the text is being developed and manuscript versions are being used as texts in the classroom. The textbook author might at best look over the solutions in the solutions manual for gross errors before submitting the solutions manual to the publisher for typesetting and printing.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate: So my take is that you would think that those on the internet are probably just as good as the one "written" by the author. thanks for heads up.

Comment: Its always the first few that seems very difficult to solve. Once you overcome this you can master them.

Comment: @jomegaA: thanks for confidence boost !!!!